Gaussian curvature of Hyperbolic Plane.
I'm studying about Gaussian curvature from Elementary Differential Geometry - Barret O'Neill, Revised Second Edition.
More precisely, in geometric surfaces. In section 7.2, example 2.5, it comes up with an example of hyperbolic plane.
Let $h(u,v)=1-\dfrac{u^2+v^2}{4}$, we use the hyperbolic inner product $\langle v,w\rangle=\dfrac{v\cdot w}{h^2}$ where $\cdot$ denote the usual scalar product in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $h>0$, this inner product is used only on the open disk $u^2+v^2<4$ of radius $2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The resulting geometric surface is the Poincaré isk model of the hyperbolic plane $H$. It follows from Corollary 2.3 that $K=-1$.

Corollary 2.3: for the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with metric tensor $\langle v,w\rangle=v\cdot w/h^2(p)$, the Gaussian curvature is $K=h(h_{uu}+h_{vv})-(h_u^2+h_v^2).$

However, when I compute $h_u=-u/2$, $h_v=-v/2$, $h_{uu}=-\dfrac{1}{2}=h_{vv}$ I get $\dfrac{-3u^2-3v^2-4}{16}\neq -1$. I don't how if I'm computing something wrong (tried many times), or if I'm not taking something into account about computing in a surface. Any help would be appreciated.

It looks to me O'Neill's formula works: We have $h_{uu} + h_{vv} = -1$ and $h_u^2 + h_v^2 = \frac{1}{4}(u^2+v^2)$. ;) If that doesn't resolve things, maybe edit in your calculations?

I was doing $-1/2-1/2=-1/4$ haha, ty!

It happens to us all, and once you see it, it's hard to unsee!
